# Selenium C# WebDriver: Wait until element is present

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I want to make sure that an element is present before the webdriver starts doing stuff.

I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
wait.Until(By.Id("login"));
```

I'm mainly struggling how to setup up the anonymous function...

Comment: FYI - it's cleaner to build your timespan like this `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`. It makes it more clear IMO

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Alternatively you can use an implicit wait:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
> amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
> not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
> implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

Comment: thanks, the new syntax is : driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @RedaBalkouch, the syntax Mike used in his Answer is correct. It's C#

Comment: If you choose to use implicit waits, be careful not to use explicit waits. That can cause some unpredictable behavior leading to bad test results. Generally speaking, I would recommend using explicit waits over implicit waits.

Comment: This method is now deprecated, you should instead use the property ImplicitWait : `Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);`

Comment: I used the approach provided and found the method was deprecated as pointed out by Samuel. Checking for the existence of an item now waits up to the specified time.

Answer (score 300):

**Using the [solution provided by Mike Kwan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present/6993597#6993597) may have an impact in overall testing performance, since the implicit wait will be used in all FindElement calls.**

Many times you'll want the FindElement to fail right away when an element is not present (you're testing for a malformed page, missing elements, etc.). With the implicit wait these operations would wait for the whole timeout to expire before throwing the exception. The default implicit wait is set to 0 seconds.

I've written a little extension method to IWebDriver that adds a timeout (in seconds) parameter to the `FindElement()` method. It's quite self-explanatory:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

I didn't cache the WebDriverWait object as its creation is very cheap, this extension may be used simultaneously for different WebDriver objects, and I only do optimizations when ultimately needed.

Usage is straightforward:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/mypage");
var btn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#login_button"));
btn.Click();
var employeeLabel = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#VCC_VSL"), 10);
Assert.AreEqual("Employee", employeeLabel.Text);
driver.Close();
```

Comment: In case someone wonder, `WebDriverWait` are from the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` namespace and comes in a separate package called `Selenium WebDriver Support Classes` on NuGet

Comment: @Ved i could kiss you <3 been looking for it in a different dll :D

Comment: @Loudenvier Please make the first line bold so that it is more noticeable. Especially since it is not the accepted answer, although being a better and more precise approach.

Comment: @Loudenvier In a case where the  html element is not rendered into DOM it will throw NoSuchElementException , appreciate if you update the code which handle those scenario's too

Comment: @sujiths this is the expected behavior. Selenium will throw an exception if the element is not found. If you want to change this behavior simply add a `try..catch` for `NoSuchElementException` in the `FindElement` extension method and return `null` when this exception is raised. Then you'll have to check for null whenever you try to find an element with this method. Sometimes it is easier to handle exceptions than to introduce null checks everywhere... It depends on how you write your code.

Comment: `Selenium WebDriver Support Classes` is now appeared on NuGet as **"Selenium.Support"**, current version is 3.4.0

Comment: I still had a lot of errors until I used this line `return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));` and it works great now. Heads up in case anyone else gets random elements not found still.

Answer (score 90):

You can also use

**ExpectedConditions.ElementExists**

So you will search for an element availability like that

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.Id(login))));
```

[Source](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs)

Comment: Agreed, this is far more useful than a mere timeout (in cases where you're dynamically loading an object).

Comment: Whilst this works. It is now marked as deprecated, so should be avoided.

Comment: Here's the new approach (not deprecated): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867605/331281

Comment: Note that, at this time, the `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` (referred to by @Dejan above) "is not maintained, issues will not be fixed, PRs will not be accepted". (source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4387#issuecomment-370502866). Its publisher is seeking a maintainer to take it over from him.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 32):

Here's a variation of [Loudenvier's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present/7312740#7312740) that also works for getting multiple elements:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => (drv.FindElements(by).Count > 0) ? drv.FindElements(by) : null);
        }
        return driver.FindElements(by);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I've just added this to my own library! That's the beauty of sharing code!!!

Comment: I'd suggest one addition to that.  You could catch the NoSuchElement solution and return null in that instance.  Then you could create an extension method called .exists that returns true unless the IWebElement is null.

Answer (score 21):

Inspired by [Loudenvier's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present/7312740#7312740), here's an extension method that works for all ISearchContext objects, not just IWebDriver, which is a specialization of the former. This method also supports waiting until the element is displayed.

```
static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Find an element, waiting until a timeout is reached if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The search context.</param>
    /// <param name="by">Method to find elements.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">How many seconds to wait.</param>
    /// <param name="displayed">Require the element to be displayed?</param>
    /// <returns>The found element.</returns>
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this ISearchContext context, By by, uint timeout, bool displayed=false)
    {
        var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
        wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        return wait.Until(ctx => {
            var elem = ctx.FindElement(by);
            if (displayed && !elem.Displayed)
                return null;

            return elem;
        });
    }
}
```

#### Example usage:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
var main = driver.FindElement(By.Id("main"));
var btn = main.FindElement(By.Id("button"));
btn.Click();
var dialog = main.FindElement(By.Id("dialog"), 5, displayed: true);
Assert.AreEqual("My Dialog", dialog.Text);
driver.Close();
```

Comment: If you've set an implicit wait such as `_webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(Timeout);` that will still trump the timeout value you set here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me...? I added a `Stopwatch` around the call to the extension method and a `Console.WriteLine()` inside the lambda sent to `Until()`. The stopwatch measured almost exactly 60 seconds and only one message was written to `Console`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 13):

I *confused* an anonymous function with a predicate. Here's a little helper method:

```
   WebDriverWait wait;
    private void waitForById(string id)
    {
        if (wait == null)
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));

        //wait.Until(driver);
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(id)));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find out something like this in C#.

This is what I used in [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) - Selenium

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submit")));
```

Do import related packages.

Comment: I attempted to use this today and VS.net is giving me warnings: the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions class has been marked "deprecated" and was "migrated to DotNetSeleniumExtras" repo on https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools

Answer (score 3):

```
// Wait up to 5 seconds with no minimum for a UI element to be found
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_pagedriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement title = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("MainContentHeader"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The clickAndWait command doesn't get converted when you choose the Webdriver format in the Selenium IDE.  Here is the workaround.  Add the wait line below.  Realistically, the problem was the click or event that happened before this one—line 1 in my C# code.  But really, just make sure you have a WaitForElement before any action where you're referencing a "By" object.

**HTML code:**

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">xxxxx</a>
```

**C#/NUnit code:**

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("z")).Click;
driver.WaitForElement(By.LinkText("xxxxx"));
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("xxxxx")).Click();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public bool doesWebElementExist(string linkexist)
{
     try
     {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(linkexist));
        return true;
     }
     catch (NoSuchElementException e)
     {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: The above code is to check whether the a particular element is present or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
 New WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(Function(d) d.FindElement(By.Id("controlName")).Displayed)
```

Comment: You should explain what you have done and why this solves the problem. And please format your code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this, and it works very well:

```
public static bool elexists(By by, WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void waitforelement(WebDriver driver, By by)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (elexists(by, driver))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can add more than 30 attempts and shorten the period to less than 1 second to check.

Usage:

```
waitforelement(driver, By.Id("login"));
IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
login.Click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

**Use namespace:**

```
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
```

**In code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("login")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit Wait

```
public static  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
```

Example:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(UiprofileCre.UiaddChangeUserLink));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order, in particular how it is different from previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to wait too long before the element changes. In this code the webdriver waits for up to 2 seconds before it continues.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Name("html-name")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Used [Rn222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present/10017032#10017032) and [aknuds1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present/13291021#13291021) to use an ISearchContext that returns either a single element, or a list. And a minimum number of elements can be specified:

```
public static class SearchContextExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Method that finds an element based on the search parameters within a specified timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context where this is searched. Required for extension methods</param>
    /// <param name="by">The search parameters that are used to identify the element</param>
    /// <param name="timeOutInSeconds">The time that the tool should wait before throwing an exception</param>
    /// <returns> The first element found that matches the condition specified</returns>
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this ISearchContext context, By by, uint timeOutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeOutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds);
            return wait.Until<IWebElement>(ctx => ctx.FindElement(by));
        }
        return context.FindElement(by);
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Method that finds a list of elements based on the search parameters within a specified timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context where this is searched. Required for extension methods</param>
    /// <param name="by">The search parameters that are used to identify the element</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutInSeconds">The time that the tool should wait before throwing an exception</param>
    /// <returns>A list of all the web elements that match the condition specified</returns>
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this ISearchContext context, By by, uint timeoutInSeconds)
    {

        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
            return wait.Until<IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>(ctx => ctx.FindElements(by));
        }
        return context.FindElements(by);
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Method that finds a list of elements with the minimum amount specified based on the search parameters within a specified timeout.<br/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context where this is searched. Required for extension methods</param>
    /// <param name="by">The search parameters that are used to identify the element</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutInSeconds">The time that the tool should wait before throwing an exception</param>
    /// <param name="minNumberOfElements">
    ///     The minimum number of elements that should meet the criteria before returning the list <para/>
    ///     If this number is not met, an exception will be thrown and no elements will be returned
    ///     even if some did meet the criteria
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>A list of all the web elements that match the condition specified</returns>
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this ISearchContext context, By by, uint timeoutInSeconds, int minNumberOfElements)
    {
        var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
        }

        // Wait until the current context found the minimum number of elements. If not found after timeout, an exception is thrown
        wait.Until<bool>(ctx => ctx.FindElements(by).Count >= minNumberOfElements);

        // If the elements were successfuly found, just return the list
        return context.FindElements(by);
    }

}
```

**Example usage:**

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost");
var main = driver.FindElement(By.Id("main"));
// It can be now used to wait when using elements to search
var btn = main.FindElement(By.Id("button"), 10);
btn.Click();
// This will wait up to 10 seconds until a button is found
var button = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button"), 10)
// This will wait up to 10 seconds until a button is found, and return all the buttons found
var buttonList = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button"), 10)
// This will wait for 10 seconds until we find at least 5 buttons
var buttonsMin = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button"), 10, 5);
driver.Close();
```

Comment: Exception at: return wait.Until<IWebElement>(ctx => ctx.FindElement(by));

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm separating page elements definitions and page test scenarios using an already-found IWebElement for visibility, it could be done like this:

```
public static void WaitForElementToBecomeVisibleWithinTimeout(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, int timeout)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ElementIsVisible(element));
}

private static Func<IWebDriver, bool> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return driver => {
        try
        {
            return element.Displayed;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // If element is null, stale or if it cannot be located
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the reusable function to wait for an element present in the DOM using an *explicit wait*.

```cs
public void WaitForElement(IWebElement element, int timeout = 2)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
    wait.Until<bool>(driver =>
    {
        try
        {
            return element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please don't post code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple solutions already posted that work great!  However, just in case anyone needs something else, I thought I would post two solutions that I personally used in Selenium C# to test if an element is present!

```
public static class IsPresent
{
    public static bool isPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By bylocator)
    {

        bool variable = false;
        try
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(bylocator);
            variable = element != null;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException){

        }
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Here is the second:

```
public static class IsPresent2
{
    public static bool isPresent2(this IWebDriver driver, By bylocator)
    {
        bool variable = true;
        try
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(bylocator);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            variable = false;
        }
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element_by_id('someId').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someAnotherId'))
```

From *EC* (import of *expected_conditions*), you can choose other conditions as well.
Try this: *[Expected conditions Support](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)*

Comment: This question is tagged C#, not Python. This answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that like this:

```
public static IWebElement WaitForObject(IWebDriver DriverObj, By by, int TimeOut = 30)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait Wait1 = new WebDriverWait(DriverObj, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOut));
        var WaitS = Wait1.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
        return WaitS[0];
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        Reports.TestStep("Wait for Element(s) with xPath was failed in current context page.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it different from previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverWait` won't take effect.

```cs
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(
    new FirefoxOptions().PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager
);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("xxx");
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
    .Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("xxx"))); // A tag that close to the end
```

This would immediately throw an exception once the page was "interactive". I don't know why, but the timeout acts as if it does not exist.

Perhaps `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` works, but I didn't try. It's official, but it was split out into another NuGet package. You can refer to *[C# Selenium 'ExpectedConditions is obsolete'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334)*.

I use `FindElements` and check `Count == 0`. If true, use `await Task.Delay`. It's really not quite efficient.

Comment: What is the idea of using 'new' without assignment?

Comment: It's only a test. I think it's the same as the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.Id("login")));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order, in particular how it is different from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Using C# Extension Method : we can solve the problem of wait until element to be visible.**
Max reties for a particular element is 100.

```
public static bool WaitForElementToBeVisible(IWebDriver browser, By by)
        {
            int attemptToFindElement = 0;
            bool elementFound = false;
            IWebElement elementIdentifier = null;
            do
            {
                attemptToFindElement++;
                try
                {
                    elementIdentifier = browser.FindWebElement(by);
                    elementFound = (elementIdentifier.Displayed && elementIdentifier.Enabled) ? true : false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    elementFound = false;
                }

            }
            while (elementFound == false && attemptToFindElement < 100);

            return elementFound;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I use the following approach, which I also implemented in my latest project [SeleniumSharper](https://github.com/maik-hasler/SeleniumSharper), which aims to simplify and enhance the Selenium experience.

What's cool about the approach is, that it will work with any instance of `ISearchContext`, which means you can either call the `Wait()` method with an `IWebDriver` or `IWebElement`.

First, you need to implement this extension method.

```cs
public static class SearchContextExtensions
{
    public static Waiter<ISearchContext> Wait(this ISearchContext searchContext, int timeoutInSeconds = 0)
    {
        var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(searchContext)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)
        };

        return new Waiter<ISearchContext>(wait);
    }
}
```

where `Waiter.cs` looks like this

```cs
public sealed class Waiter<T>
{
    private readonly DefaultWait<T> _wait;

    public Waiter(DefaultWait<T> wait)
    {
        _wait = wait;
    }

    public TResult Until<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> condition)
    {
        return _wait.Until(condition);
    }
}
```

After that you need to create a specific condition to satisfy, for example:

```cs
public static class WaitConditions
{
    public static Func<ISearchContext, IWebElement> ElementExists(By by)
    {
        return (searchContext) => searchContext.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

You can then wait for the condition by chaining up all the methods:

```cs
var webdriver = new ChromeDriver();

var locator = By.CssSelector(".myCssClass");

webdriver.Wait(30).Until(WaitConditions.ElementExists(locator));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try on this, it works for me, refered from a blog post

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

  IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
  {
      
      try
      {
          return d.FindElement(By.Id("day"));
      }

      catch (Exception ex) when (ex is StaleElementReferenceException or NoSuchElementException)
      {
          return null;
      }
  });

  IWebElement dayField = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("day"));
  dayField.SendKeys("12");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).
   Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy((By.Id("toast-container"))));
```

Comment: ExpectedConditions is deprecated

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score -1):

The first answer is good, but my problem was that **unhandled exceptions didn't close web driver properly**, and it kept the same first value I had used which was 1 second.

If you get the same problem, *restart your Visual Studio* and ensure that *all the exceptions are handled* properly.

Comment: By now you should know that there is no ordering to answers in Stack Overflow, so there is no "first answer"

Comment: ```Restart your Visual Studio```, not really solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to wait in Selenium for a condition:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(m_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(d => ReadCell(row, col) != "");
```

`ReadCell(row, col) != ""` can be any condition. Like this way because:

- it's mine
- allows inlining