# Selenium c# cannot locate element with text

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am new to Selenium in C#. I tried to use

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("someId")));
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("someId"))).SelectByText("someText");
```

I got error like this in my NUnit output:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Cannot locate element with
>   text: someText

But when I replace wait.Unitil statement with Tread.Sleep(3000), my test could pass without error.

Need some help. Please advise.

Comment: most likely you're not giving enough time for the elements to load into the DOM before you try accessing them.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Do you mean the text element loading into the DOM? My point is why wait.Until does not work.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084078/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-unable-to-find-element/24534900#24534900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work:

```
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='someId']//*[text()='someText']")));
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("someId"))).SelectByText("someText");
```

But will be good to refactor this into single until, something like:

```
wait.Until(d =>
{
new SelectElement(d.FindElement(By.Id("someId"))).SelectByText("someText");
return d;
});
```