# WebDriverWait is not working for DialogFragment - C#, Appium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm using Appium .NET [driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver) to write some automated tests for one Android app.

I need to add a wait to find one element as it takes some time to load.

If I use `Thread.Sleep` it works fine but it nasty way so thought to check with `WebDriverWait` but using `WebDriverWait` the test failed and not able to find the element.

**Working code:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    IWebElement obj =  driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Get Started']");
    obj.Click();
}
```

**Not working:**

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var obj = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Get Started']"), 15);
        obj.Click();
    }
```

`FindElement` is the extension method written by Loudenvier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

**Log:** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4gtyidlk57nzf3/AABAGUSo7KwfFrbmsfZBKxPIa?dl=0) is my Appium log from thread sleep and webdriverwait approach. Appreciate your help.

**Edit1:** the button element I'm trying to find is part of a Android DialogFragment. This DialogFragment comes up when user open the the app for first time, this is a kind of welcome screen.

What I noticed `WebDriverWait` actually wait in the primary app fragment and trying to search for the element and it fails. But `Thread.Sleep` works because in that case the `DialogFragment` get loaded on top of the primary app fragment and then webdriver search the element in the correct fragment. I tried with the `ImplicitlyWait` and `explicitwait` but result is same.

Is there any better way to wait for DialogFragment?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `explicit` wait and wait for driver to find element? Plus, the find element mechanisms look different in your code above.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  By byXpath = By.XPath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Get Started']");
  IWebElement webElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d=>d.FindElement(byXpath));
  webElement.Click();
}
```

Comment: Sorry explicit and implicit wait doesn't work in this scenario, please see the reason in the question edit section.

Comment: I am not very familiar with `Appium` but seems like you need to switch the focus on the DialogFragment somehow