# .NET Selenium NoSuchElementException; WebDriverWait.Until() doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, nosuchelementexception

We have a .NET 4.5, MVC, C# project.  We're using Selenium for UI tests, and the tests keep intermittently failing on lines that we have `wait.Until()`.  One such example is:

```
NoSuchElementException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#assessment-472 .status-PushedToSEAS"}
```

It's thrown right here:

```
Thread.Sleep(600);
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#" + assessmentQueueId + " .status-PushedToSEAS")));
```

I can see that the browser opens, I see it get to that point, and I can inspect element to see that the element exists.  Its id is exactly correct.

We have this problem **A LOT** and so far the solution has been to throw `Thread.Sleep(600)` (or some similar time) in front of it.  The whole point of `wait.Until()` is to not have to do that, and this is making our test suites get very long.  Also, as you can see in the example above, sometimes we have the problem even after putting a `Thread.Sleep()` in front of it and we have to extend the time.

Why is .NET Selenium's `WebDriver.Until()` not working, and is there a different way to do the same thing without just waiting a set period of time?  Again, the problem is intermittent, meaning that it only happens sometimes, and it could happen at any number of `wait.Until()` statements, not just the one shown!

**Edit:**

This is a class variable.
`private WebDriverWait wait;`

It is instantiated like this:

```
this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: How do you define `wait`? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe see the above edit.  Sorry I neglected to mention that.

Comment: @alecxe I'm doing that...see edit again; sorry again.

Comment: Does it actually wait the full length of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just not use `WebDriverWait.Until()`, and use implicit waits on the main driver instead:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I give full credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present) on a different question for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            try
            {
                if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
                {
                    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
                    return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
                }
                return driver.FindElement(by);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

or if you are having

> NoSuchElementException

try this code

```
 try
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
            }
            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
```