# Selecting Radio Buttons with XPath in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I am trying to select a specific radio button with the XPath command:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(@input id,   'SearchTypePatientNameDob')]")).Click();
```

The list that contains the button I want is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <input id="RadioButtonSearchTypePatientNameDob" type="radio"      value="SearchTypePatientNameDob" name="SearchType">
    <span class="Instructions">Patient Name / Patient Date of Birth</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My command can not find the button to select/click it.  Any suggestions would be of great benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to locate the `input` element, not the `td` element:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'SearchTypePatientNameDob')]
```

Note that I don't see any legitimate reason why would not you use a simple `By.Id` locator:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("RadioButtonSearchTypePatientNameDob")).Click();
```

You may also need to explicitly [wait for the element to be present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/771848).

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!  I would expect this command to work, however, I continue to get an error saying that it does not exist on the page.

Comment: @Rinktacular alright, there can be multiple reasons. First of all, do you see any iframe/frame elements on the page? Thanks.

Comment: @Rinktacular I've also added a link to the answer providing the way to wait for element to become present.

Comment: Yes, there is one.  I apologize, I am unfamiliar with this type of <tag> and didn't know it was important to the original question.  It is quite large, but I can post it if it will assist you/myself.

Comment: I have been trying to wait for the element to appear with `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));`

..but that was before I knew that <iframe> was important to the solution.

Comment: @Rinktacular yeah, if the element is inside the iframe, in order to locate the element, you need to switch to the `iframe` using `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(<frame name or id or index or an element referring to the frame>)`.

Comment: @Rinktacular yeah, so, basically, switch to the iframe and then try to find the element.

Comment: So given the information:

    `<iframe id="childFrame" name="childFrame" onload="AjaxDocument.registerFrames('childFrame');" src="javascript:&quot;&quot;;" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
Am I using the command correctly?
`driver.SwitchTo().Frame("<childFrame>");`

Comment: @Rinktacular nope, `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("childFrame");`

Comment: Using that line of code now comes back with an error saying that childFrame can not be found.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rinktacular is it the only iframe on the page? If yes, you may need to wait for this iframe element to be present in the DOM (follow the link in the answer). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, there is more than one iframe and  I will work with the link you provided. +1

Comment: @Rinktacular then, you need to switch to iframes one by one, going from the parent to the child frame.