# Selenium is telling me the ID doesn't exist

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

When I run the following program it runs absolutely fine, until I get to filling out the form on the webclip section. Once it gets there it says the id "txtTemplateName" can't be found. I copied and pasted that name directly from Inspecting the element. It isn't that i'm not giving it enough time to load either, I've given it a full 5 seconds in the past just to make sure, and still nothing.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Build1Evan
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IWebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();   
        driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");

        Process.Start(@FILE"); // This is just an Auto IT Script to get me by a login window

        bool loginCheck1 = driver1.FindElements(By.Id("btnLoginAgain")).Count() > 0;
        if (loginCheck1 == true)
        {
            driver1.FindElement(By.Id("btnLoginAgain")).Click();
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        driver1.FindElement(By.LinkText("Configuration")).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);                             
        driver1.FindElement(By.LinkText("Payloads")).Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        driver1.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("WebClip")).Click();
                // BELOW IS WHERE I ENCOUNTER THE ISSUE 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        driver1.FindElement(By.Id("txtTemplateName")).SendKeys("TESTING");
    }
}
}
```

I also encounter the error when I try selecting any other element in the form, rather it be a button or another text field.

EDIT: [PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7emY.png) AS ASKED

EDIT 2: [PHOTO 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz6N6.jpg) Also just a FYI i have had no problems using Selenium IDE, it is easily able to select the element and fill it in.

Comment: We need to know what page your hitting to help you

Comment: Or even a screenshot of the inspect element

Comment: Regardless of the goal/implementation, would be good to see if using built-in WebDriverWait might help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present.

Comment: @KeithM just added the photo for you

Comment: @KarenClark probably a good idea, i will look into that!

Comment: Is the form inside `iframe`?

Comment: @guy i don't believe so, if i run through this with selenium IDE it says im swapping to frame foo... What exactly does that mean

Comment: Look for tag `iframe` in the html. If the form inside that tag you need to switch to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, I think your app embed the form by using `<object id="panelcontentobject" data="...`.

In case the form is really inside object tag, you have to create a WebElement of the object tag then use JavaScriptExecutor to retrieve attribute or interact with the form. 
For example,

```
IWebElement objectTag= driver.FindElement(By.Id("panelcontentobject"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("return (arguments[0].contentDocument.getElementById('txtTemplateName')).click()",objectTag);
```

Please see Examples from http://aksahu.blogspot.com/2015/05/dealing-with-object-tags-in-selenium-webdriver.html?m=1

Comment: sorry for taking so long to get back check my most recent edit.

Comment: Thank you for you're response! I just realized i can access the objects directly from a different URL and am going to work forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

The form is probably inside `iframe`, you need to switch to it before you can perform actions on elements inside it:

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.Id(frameId));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
```

You can also use explicit wait to make sure the element you want is visible and you can interact with it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("txtTemplateName"))).SendKeys("TESTING");
```