# NoSuchElementException despite using WebDriverWait

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium to locate an element and populate it with text. When I browse to my URL, a text box shows first which loads the page. Once the app is loaded, a login username/password is shown. I just want to wait until the login username/password is displayed to avoid a NoSuchElementException. I've referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present) but cannot get any of the solutions there to work.

When I run the test, it does not wait for the element to appear and immediately fails on `x.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")` with a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"<my path>"))
{
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<my url>");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
    var userName = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")));

    userName.SendKeys("username");

    IWebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
    pass.SendKeys("password");
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How should I change my code to wait for the `UserName` id to be present before looking for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to wait first invisibility of loading element then go to wait for visibility of username as below :-

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ID("id of loading element ")));

//Now go to find username element 
var userName = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ID("UserName")));
userName.SendKeys("username");
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up Just using `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("UserName")));` and that worked.