# How to convert Selenium IWebElement in Selenium Locator By C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, pageobjects

How to convert IWebElement in Locator Selenium WebDriver Page Objects?

I work like this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "user")]
        public IWebElement txtUser { get; set; }

        public void fillUserField(string user)
        {
           wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("user")));
           txtUser.SendKeys(user);
        }
```

I do not want to repeat the ID "user" in wait.

I don't work like this:

```
    public void fillUserField(string user)
    {   // TO DO - Convert IWebElement in Locator (BY)
        //Argument1: Cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.By'  
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.**ElementIsVisible(txtUser)**);
        txtUser.SendKeys(user);
    }
```

Is possible? Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to stick with this model you can create a separate method that takes `IWebElement`, pass it your elements (e.g. `txtUser`), and then handle in that method with a try catch waiting until the element is found/ready/visible. I can't see how to make `wait` in your scenario work without duplicating the By locator type string. IMO, the ideal solution for wait on elements is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/2246511   But I don't know how you could use that with PageObjects.

Answer (score -1):

You would declare a locator at the top of the class.

```
public By userLocator = By.Id("user");
```

and then use it like

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(userLocator));
```

Comment: You would still have the duplication that Ramon is trying to avoid with the FindsBy attribute of the txtUser property he already has and then again in the userLocator field you recommend.

Comment: @jibbs Yes but he wouldn't need the `FindsBy` at that point so the duplication would be removed.

Comment: @JeffC This solution does not solve a duplication, but I solved the problem like this: wait.Until (ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable (+1 overload)); Thanks