# xpath to get column inside a table

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to validate "img" properties from the following html code[please refer image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjizm.png)

**Code Here**

//table[@class='row header-logo' and @style='border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%']

Kindly help me to get the exact xpath to validate "img" properties by title, alt,src

Comment: html is not standard xml, so xpath is not guaranteed. try other libraries, check [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: Thanks Lei Yang. Kindly suggest me some library names as the reference you shared got lot of information which is confusing :(

Comment: pick the highest votes.

Comment: Instead of providing image, please share html code.

Comment: Hi Jaihnish, entire HTML code is placed at https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wxi4tixcqjsaz3/Dhana.txt?dl=0 . Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

First, locate the `<img>` with this XPath:

```
//img[@alt='Intel']
```

Explained:

- `//` - Selects first matching node
- `img[@alt='Intel']` - Select `<img>` where `alt` equals string `'Intel'`

---

Then, use [`IWebElement.GetAttribute`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) to get the `<img>` attributes to validate:

```
IWebDriver driver;

try
{
    // locate image
    IWebElement image = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@alt='Intel']"));

    // get image attributes
    string title = image.GetAttribute("title");
    string alt = image.GetAttribute("alt");
    string src = image.GetAttribute("src");

    // validate title, alt, and src
    // EX: Assert.AreEqual("Intel", title);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
    // image does not exist, handle accordingly
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Webdriver is not able to identify "img" element. This is the main root cause for this issue.

Comment: it says element is not found.

Comment: I suggest researching Implicit Waits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present