# How to wait for an element until it is found?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want my code to wait for an element explicitly. i.e. No time limit for waiting.
It should wait for an element until that element is found, then whether it takes 1 hour or more.

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: Maybe you can set maximum waiting time, say `100*100` or something big.

Comment: what does **element** mean exactly?

Comment: How do you "look for" that element? Is it a database query or a webrequest or maybe a file on the filesystem? Can you use async/await, or maybe work with events/listeners? Or simply `while (!found) { Sleep(...); found = checkIfFound(); }`?

Comment: For example, After login on facebook or any other site I want to wait for an element (it could be LOGOUT button or notification bar) just to confirm that page is completely loaded. @LeiYang

Comment: In c# we find element by, 
driverff.findelement(by.id/class("id/class name")); 
on webpage  @Corak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium c# Webdriver: Wait Until Element is Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

You can use do-while loop to wait for that element as it won't appear on screen.

you can take reference of below code.

```
isElementDisplayed =driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).isDisplayed(); 

do{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} while(isElementDisplayed == true)
```