# Selenium WebDriverWait wait.Until type arguments cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, selenium, dom-events, javascript-injection

I have the following snippet of code:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("loginButton")));
            driver.FindElementById("loginButton").Click();

            wait.Until(JavascriptInjector.GetDocumentReadyState(driver) == expectedReadyState);
```

`JavascriptInjector.GetDocumentReadyState(driver)` executes `return document.readyState` in the Chrome browser and returns the value as a string.  `expectedReadyState` is of type `string`.  However, I am getting the following error:

> "The type argument cannot be inferred from the usage."

Any suggestions as to how to get past this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you update the question with your Manual Step which you are trying to Automate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Until` method of `WebDriverWait` does not take a `bool` as an argument. It takes a function taking an `IWebDriver`, and returning an inferrable type (of which `bool` is one). What you want is something like the following:

```
wait.Until((d) => { return JavascriptInjector.GetDocumentReadyState(d) == expectedReadyState; });
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  My wait is working properly now with this update.  I'll also go back and re-read the How to Ask documentation as suggested above.