# How can I wait for an element from another element in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, wait

Is there a way to perform a `wait.Until` by somehow searching the element from another element, rather than from the whole driver?

example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSec));

IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
```

I cannot modify the `'by'` to be too specific and when it is searched under the driver and gets the wrong element.

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
```

this option also searches under the `driver`.
I want something like this:

```
public static IWebElement WaitElement(this IWebElement webElement, IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSec = 5)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSec));
                IWebElement element = wait.Until(webElement.FindElement(by));
        }
```

When I try to write this code I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw1Y2.png)

Comment: There's three [types](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/). See [wait until an element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

Comment: What you've done is actually correct. You can find child element from patent element.

Comment: What I have written (last code) is not 'legal' and is not accepted

Comment: Use By.CssSelector("#parentId #childId");

Comment: Daphne, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same issue where I'm looping through found elements and need to wait on a sub element of each element.

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but hopefully will help someone else. Just change the syntax of your last line in the 3rd option to the following:

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(d => webElement.FindElement(by));
```