# C# Selenium Web driver: Not able to select value from dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, dropdown

Please refer screenshot below.
[image]
[image]
I am trying to provide value in dropdown field and select the very fisrt value. But it is not populating.
Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Please Try in this way

```
var ul = driver.findelement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'your class name')]")).ToList();//loop over here. or if you know index than use it directly.
                var Select = ul[your index].FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
                foreach (IWebElement item in Select)
                {
                    if (item.Text.Trim() == "Your Text")
                    {
                        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                        while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds < 1500)
                        {
                             Application.DoEvents();
                             System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                        }
                        item.Click();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! Above worked for me, but it works only while debugging. When i run the project it doesnot populate the value from dropdown. Am i missing anything?

Comment: var ul = driver.findelement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'your class name')]")).ToList();
                var Select = ul[0].FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ToList();
                foreach (IWebElement item in Select)
                {
                    if (item.Text.Trim() == "TE_GL1")
                    {
                        item.Click();
                        // WebExtention.Wait(500); I am using Chrome
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
                        break;
                    }
                }

Comment: Also i get OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document at if statement

Comment: @neeta Jadhav i thing you need to use WebExtention.Wait(1500) before click()

Comment: and you can handle this StaleElementReferenceException: error using try{}catch(NoSuchElementException){ goto your step} and you can go further on error line using goto. i hope you understand.

Comment: What is this WebExtension. I cannot use it my code. Do we need to refer any namespace?

Comment: No, You can not use in your code. this is one class i created in my code and wait is a method of class .

Comment: You can use this like
 DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds < 1500)
            {
                //Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  when you open your dropdown.

```
  Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".col-xs-3")).First(e => e.Text = "TE_GL1").Click();
```

Or just click first element

```
  Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".col-xs-3")).First().Click();
```

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out `Thread.Sleep(5000);` worked!

Comment: If you have to use this trick it often means the DOM is not completely loaded yet. Instead of Sleep you better `Wait` for an element to appear. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/578411