# How to wait until element is shown? selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to do some actions when an element is shown but I don't know how to wait for it, on selenium document they use `Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.xPath("")));`, but when I try to do it ExpectedConditions doesn't exists so, how can I wait for an element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium C# WebDriver: Wait until element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

ExpectedConditions is under SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

```
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("")));
```