# Selenium - Force click on non-visible element

Tags: c#, selenium, web, automation, .net-4.5

I'm using C# Selenium.WebDriver.2.44.0
On some 3rd party site I'm trying to press an element and get this:

```
var myWebElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.=' some value']            
myWebElement.Click();
```

I get the element and on click I get this:

```
{"element not visible\n  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"}
```

The item is within some sub menu revealing after I successfully press the parent menu. Also put 5 seconds sleep to be safe that the accordion is well seen (and it is well seen in my eyes).

Question - on 3rd party site how can I force the click on this item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [selenium webdriver: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082946/selenium-webdriver-org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-n)

Answer (score 0):

You could try bringing it to the top by changing the z-index with driver.execute_script().

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inbuilt functions and WebDriver waits

```
var myWebElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.=' some value']
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.FindElement, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(myWebElement));

Actions action  = new Actions(Driver.FindElement);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

myWebElement.Click();
```

Comment: Question is related to **non-visible element** you answer will fail `var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(myWebElement));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Selenium executes actions one after another, but something like "show a sub menu" is lost between actions.

You're likely going to have to use an `Actions` chain for this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);

action.MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(By(ParentElementSelector)))
    .click()
    .MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.=' some value'])))
    .click()
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

This will move to the parent element, click, then move to the element you wish to find, then click.  It will perform all of these as one action, which should be able to click the sub menu element.

Comment: mmm, almost there - it did the accordion thing and now the second item is seen - but didn't do the "second click" - however no exception thrown...

Comment: If you link to the third party site, I can take a look at it later and possibly come up with a solution.

Answer (score -1):

When an element is not visible u can try this...It works for me

```
IWebElement WEHiddenID = driver.FindElement(By.Id(""));
WEHiddenID.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```