# How to click a href link using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a *html* `href` link

```
<a href="/docs/configuration">App Configuration</a>
```

using Selenium I need to click the link. Currently, I am using below code -

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='App Configuration']")).click();
```

But it's not redirecting to the page. I also tried below code -

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[@href ='/docs/configuration']")).click();
```

But this is throwing below exception -

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
```

The link is visible and page is completely loaded. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 34):

```
 webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/docs/configuration']")).click();
```

The above line works fine. Please remove the space after href.

Is that element is visible in the page, if the element is not visible please scroll down the page then perform click action.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("App Configuration")).click()
```

Other Approaches will be

```
JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary(); 
jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(selenium, "triggerMouseEventAt", elementToClick,"click", "0,0");
```

or

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

For detailed answer, [View this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082946/selenium-webdriver-org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-n)

Answer (score 4):

Thi is your code :

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[@href ='/docs/configuration']")).click();
```

You missed the Quotation mark

it should be as below

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/docs/configuration']")).click();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use an explicit `wait` for the element like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("path of element"))).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `a` tag is hidden. Remember Selenium is not able to interact with hidden element. `Javascript` is the only option in that case.

```
By css = By.cssSelector("a[href='/docs/configuration']");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(css);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();" , element);
```

Comment: getting cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0] is undefined

Comment: Try `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.querySelector(\"a[href='/docs/configuration']\").click();");` instead of the 3 lines in the answer

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: Seems like wait issue to me. Add some explicit wait and try

Answer (score 1):

> How to click on link without  using click method in selenum?

This is a tricky question. Follow the below steps:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
String gmaillink= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&ogbl']")).getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(gmaillink);
driver.get(gmaillink);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Action class to reach the element

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='AppConfiguration']")));
action.Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers seem a bit too complicated. This worked for me.
Give the svg tag an id and then find the Element by that id:

This is your svg:

```
<svg id="element-id"><use href="/...."></use></svg>
```

Then do it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element-id")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

For the links if you use `linkText();` it is more effective than the any other locator.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("App Configuration")).click();
```

Comment: You forgot a bracket.

Comment: doesn't work for pages with language based on user IP

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **App Configuration** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("App Configuration")).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/docs/configuration']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/docs/configuration' and text()='App Configuration']")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally, to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("App Configuration"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href='/docs/configuration']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/docs/configuration' and text()='App Configuration']"))).click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible while clicking a checkbox through SeleniumWebDriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720891/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible/52744466#52744466)
- [How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException using Selenium with Java in Amazon Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358375/how-to-resolve-org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-using-selenium-wit/48358593#48358593)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using this one :  .name of the class > a

What we mean is fetch the class followed by its href

e.g. could be (.offset3 >a).click()  , here offset3 is the class and a is the anchor tag

sample code
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xpath` as follows, try this one :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//[@href='/docs/configuration'])")).click();
```