# How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException using Selenium with Java in Amazon Sign In

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

```
package newpackage;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class OpenAmazon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");

        List<WebElement> yourOrders= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class='nav-line-2']"));

    //third element is the your orders
        WebElement yourOrder=yourOrders.get(2);
    //mouse hover on it to get the sign button
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);    
        act.moveToElement(yourOrder).build();   

        //click on SignIn button
        List<WebElement> signIn= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class='nav-action-inner']"));
        signIn.get(0).click();

    }

}
```

---

i am using above code to Sign In in Amazon.i am getting Element NotVisibleException for SignIn Button which appears after hover on yourOrders.how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to `Sign In` in Amazon you were getting `ElementNotVisibleException` for `SignIn` Button as the `Locator Strategy` you had adapted wasn't uniquely identifying the `Sign In` button.

To `click()` on **Sign In** button in `http://www.amazon.in` you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav-a nav-a-2' and @id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[@class='nav-line-1']")).click();
```