# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible while clicking a checkbox through SeleniumWebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have to select a checkbox that is contained in the following HTML snippet.
The checkbox is contained in an input tag

```html
<div formarrayname="entityTypes" fxlayout="" fxlayoutgap="10px" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                  <div class="form-row ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutgap="10px" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                    <app-checkbox formcontrolname="isSelected" _nghost-c26="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><div _ngcontent-c26="" class="checkbox-wrapper">

  <span _ngcontent-c26="" class="tix-checkbox" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="start center" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; max-height: 100%; place-content: center flex-start; align-items: center;">
    <!---->
    <input _ngcontent-c26="" type="checkbox" name="undefined" class="ng-star-inserted" style="" xpath="1">
  
      Funder
      <label _ngcontent-c26=""></label>
  </span>
  
  <!---->

  <!---->

</div>
</app-checkbox>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I have tried various things to identify it and select it but it is never visible.
I have printed out the text of the label of the checkbox to the console so can't understand why the checkbox itself is not visible.
The following java code successfully prints the label but fails to click the checkbox and throws the error element not visible.

```
//print text of input box
WebElement labelFunder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@fxflex='50']//div[3]//div[1]//app-checkbox[1]//div[1]//span[1]//input[1]"));
String textFunderLabel2 = labelFunder.getAttribute("innerText").toString();
System.out.println(textFunderLabel);
labelFunder.click();
```

I have tried different waits but that has not been successful either.

```
//select the funder checkbox
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@fxflex='50']//div[3]//div[1]//app-checkbox[1]//div[1]//span[1]//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
//WebElement checkbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/main[1]/section[1]/div[2]/app-company-detail[1]/div[2]/form[1]/md-tab-group[1]/div[1]/md-tab-body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/app-checkbox[1]/div[1]/span[1]/input[1]")));
//checkbox.click();
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction here

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with javascript click:

```
public void clickElementWithJS(By locator) {
    String jsClickCode = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();";
    try {
        WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(locator);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(jsClickCode, elementToClick);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Element could not be clicked.. "  + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain this line ´arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click();´  is it always should be like this? what is arguments[0] meaning here?

Answer (score 2):

This complete error message is...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 2.05 seconds
```

...implies that the desired **element was not visible** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) while the *WebDriver* instance was trying to find it.

---

### ElementNotVisibleException

[ElementNotVisibleException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html) is thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), it is not visible, and so is not able to be interacted with. It is a *runtime* exception and have the following hierarchy:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
        org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException
            org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException
                org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException
```

---

### Field Summary

The fields of this exception are inherited from class org.openqa.selenium.[WebDriverException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html) and are as follows:

```
Modifier and Type                        Field and Description
---------------------------------        ---------------------
protected static java.lang.String        BASE_SUPPORT_URL 
static java.lang.String                  DRIVER_INFO 
static java.lang.String                  SESSION_ID
```

---

### Reason

One possitive take away from **ElementNotVisibleException** is the fact that the *WebElement* is **present** within the HTML and this exception is commonly encountered when trying to `click()` or `read` an attribute of an element that is hidden from view.

---

### Solution

As *ElementNotVisibleException* ensures that the *WebElement* is **present** within the HTML so the solution ahead would be two folds as per the next steps as detailed below:

- If you next step is to **read** any attribute of the desired element, then you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in-conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause set to [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows:

  ```
  //using id attribute
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("element_id"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  //using linkText attribute          
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("element_linkText"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  //using cssSelector     
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  //using xpath           
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- If you next step is to invoke **`click()`** on the desired element, then you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in-conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause set to [elementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) as follows:

  ```
  //using id attribute
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("element_id"))).click();
  //using linkText attribute          
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("element_linkText"))).click();
  //using cssSelector     
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector"))).click();
  //using xpath           
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).click();
  ```

---

### This usecase

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.tix-checkbox input.ng-star-inserted[name='undefined']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='tix-checkbox']//input[@class='ng-star-inserted' and @name='undefined']"))).click();
  ```