# Selenium: Element not visible exception for Webpage popup/Alert/Notification message

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate one case on the following page:

http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=4&controller=product

With step:

```
Load Page > Click 'Add to cart' > Popup appears with buttons > Press 'Proceed to checkout'
```

However, my code is failing on Click `"elementButton.click()"`

The Exception I get:

> "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible "

The element is enabled; however, it is invisible either because it's a popup and I have to move to popup window and then click check out, or Alert/Pop seems to not working.

If anyone please could assist. Many thanks in advance.

```java
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=4&controller=product");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Add to cart']")).click();

        WebElement elementButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@title,'Proceed to checkout')]"));

        System.out.println(" ****elementButton**********" + elementButton.isEnabled());  // returning true
        elementButton.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *Load Page > Click 'Add to cart' > Popup appears with buttons > Press 'Proceed to checkout'* you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=4&controller=product");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("p#add_to_cart>button span"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[title='Proceed to checkout']>span"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=4&controller=product");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Add to cart']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Proceed to checkout']/span"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: automationpractice]

> You can find a detailed discussion in [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible while clicking a checkbox through SeleniumWebDriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720891/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible/52744466#52744466)

Comment: So nice, with capture evidence

Comment: Thank you guys for assistance. I was trying implicitlyWait, probably my understanding for implicitlyWait is not correct. I thought it is similar to a thread, wait for certain time and then throw exception

Please clarify this for me

Comment: @Fay Updated the answer with a reference. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the error you get: `....element not visible`, after `Add to cart` may you need wait until the element visible.

You can use `visibilityOfElementLocated`.

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Try the bellow code:

```
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=4&controller=product");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Add to cart']")).click();

WebElement elementButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@title,'Proceed to checkout')]")));
elementButton.click();
```

Comment: Thank you, Could you please guide me why implicitlyWait doesn't work here. Isn't it implicitlyWait suppose to wait for a certain time and meanwhile if the element appears it should click if no then throw an exception


Please clarify this for me