# How to click a hyperlink without any link text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a hyperlink without a link text.

I have:

```
 <a id="fontColor" href="f?p=420181023:1:12264109389989:1416222:NO::P1_SEMCODE:20190">
     <strong>Check</strong>
 </a>
```

I've tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='f?p=420181023:1:12264109389989:1416222:NO::P1_SEMCODE:20190']")).click();
```

Causes No.SuchElementException

```
driver.findElement(By.id("fontColor")).click();
```

Does nothing

I have read different materials from different websites but it seems none mention hyperlinks without link text. Is there a alternative to

```
By.xpath()
By.id() 
By.linkText()
```

Sources:

[How to click a href link using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635228/how-to-click-a-href-link-using-selenium/30639812)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: The stackoverflow link you provided said to remove the space after href, but it looks like you didn't do that.

Comment: It was a typo, fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: How about `By.partialLinktext("Check")`?

Comment: No.SuchElementException even with partialLinktext.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure your on a page that contains that element? I would also check to see if you're in an iframe. You will need to switch to the iframe first.

Answer (score 2):

The desired element looks to be a dynamic element so invoke `click()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#fontColor[href*='P1_SEMCODE']>strong"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='fontColor' and contains(@href, 'P1_SEMCODE')]/strong[contains(., 'Check')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: What does href* represent/means, I have never seen wild card with attribute name in css or xpath ? please confirm.

Comment: @AmitJain `cssSelector` supports wildcards and `*` in _cssSelector_ is equivalent to `contains()` in _XPath_. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582353/how-to-get-selectors-with-dynamic-part-inside-using-selenium-with-python/49587006#49587006)