# clicking on hyperlink using xpath and css selector do not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like Selenium driver to click on the export button as shown in the image.
[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<a class="btn bx-noIcon-margin" rel="tooltip" title="" onclick="if (!this.getAttribute('disabled')) jq_load_dialog('/index.php/filter/export/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list',{autoOpen:false, bgiframe:false, close:'function() { $(this).dialog(\'destroy\'); }', maxHeight:2000, maxWidth:2024, modal:true, resizable:false, title:'Download as Excel file', width:400},'#jqDialog'); return false;" href="/index.php/filter/export/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list" data-original-title="Export current list"><i class="glyphicons download_alt"></i> </a>
```

I tried:
from the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635228/how-to-click-a-href-link-using-selenium)
`driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH("//a[@href='/index.php/filter/export/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list']")).click();`

but it returns

> str is not callable.

Then, I tried using CSS_SELECTOR based on [docs here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'i.glyphicons download_alt').click()
```

it returns

> NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'i.glyphicons.download_alt').click()
```

***OR*** Add the `ExplicitWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by
import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui
import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support
import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
   EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.glyphicons.download_alt")))

element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to do what you want.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.btn.bx-noIcon-margin').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click on the element in the HTML code and then click copy -> copy XPath or copy full XPath
and paste it instead of yours Xpath

Also, recommend you remove unnecessary symbols:

```
 driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your/XPath').click()
```

And may be you need to put in your code delay:

```
time.sleep(5)
```