# ElementNotVisibleException due to css style "display:none;"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When executing the following test in Firefox an "`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`" is thrown. The reason seems to be a pop-up window which appears just before the Select field (variable selectMarke) is being used (and strangely not when manually clicking through that site). I tried several possibilities which are listed in different threads but they didn't work. The cause seems to be the pop-up window.

How can I solve that problem?

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(16, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.autoscout24.de/");
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    WebElement pageWSuche = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Werkstattsuche"));
    pageWSuche.click();

    WebElement plzField = driver.findElement(By.id("cms-plz"));
    plzField.sendKeys("81243");

    WebElement findGarField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.buttonBob span input[value='Werkstätten finden']"));
    findGarField.click();

    WebElement navInspect = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Inspektion (mit Preis)"));
    navInspect.click();

    Select selectMarke = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputL[name='MakeId']")));
    selectMarke.selectByVisibleText("BMW");

    driver.quit();
```

When executing the following class on the same domain but in a different page everything is fine since no pop-up window does appear.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(16, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.autoscout24.de/");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Fahrzeugsuche"));
    element.click();

    Select selectMarke = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='make1']")));
    selectMarke.selectByVisibleText("BMW");
    Select selectModell = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='model1']")));
    selectModell.selectByValue("15779");
    Select selectPriceTo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='priceto']")));
    selectPriceTo.selectByVisibleText("100.000");
    Select selectYearFrom = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='yearfrom']")));
    selectYearFrom.selectByVisibleText("2006");
    Select selectKM = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='mileageto']")));
    selectKM.selectByVisibleText("200.000");
    Select selectFuel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='fuel']")));
    selectFuel.selectByVisibleText("Diesel");
    WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.id("zipcode"));
    location.sendKeys("München");
    Select selectRadius = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.inputFullWidth[name='zipradius']")));
    selectRadius.selectByVisibleText("200 km");

    WebElement searchBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value$='Fahrzeuge']"));
    searchBtn.click();

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: I re-checked against [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/selenium-2-0-element-is-not-currently-visible] and the problem is not the pop-up (which I "eliminated" by using the local firefox profile) but a css "display:none;" in one of the parent elements. Is there any possibility of working around that problem? Strange thing: despite that setting the user can click and select fields in that section. So that should be testable.

Answer (score 0):

This should really not happen. Actually, selenium is pretty clever in finding out wether an element is visible or not. The following code is copied directly from the Selenium atoms:

```
 // Any element with a display style equal to 'none' or that has an ancestor  
 // with display style equal to 'none' is not shown.  
 function displayed(e) {    
     if (bot.dom.getEffectiveStyle(e, 'display') == 'none') {      
         return false;    
     }        
     var parent = bot.dom.getParentElement(e);   
     return !parent || displayed(parent);  
 }
```

This allows for child elements to override a parent's `display:none`. Maybe there is something else going wrong?

One alternative would be to use jquery to sort of manually click on the submit. `Autoscout24` has some mention of jquery so it should already be embedded in the page. Then you could use something along the lines of

```
//searchBtn.click();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", searchBtn);
```

This way, you can circumvent selenium's checking of whether the element is visible or not. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a method like this, tailored to look for the display:none flag on a element:

```
public Boolean elementIsDisplayed( By locator ) {   
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    WebElement foo = wait.until( 
         ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( locator );
    if ( foo == null ) return false;
    return true;
}
```