# Set value of input instead of sendKeys() - Selenium WebDriver nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have a long string to test and `sendKeys()` takes too long. When I tried to set the value of the `text` the program crashes. I know the Selenium `sendKeys()` is the best way to test the actual user input, but for my application it takes too much time so I am trying to avoid it.

Is there a way to set the value right away?

See this quick example:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
      build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');

// find the search input field on google.com
inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));

var longstring = "test"; // not really long for the sake of this quick example

// this works but is slow
inputField.sendKeys(longstring);

// no error but no values set
inputField.value = longstring;

// Output: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setAttributes'

inputField.setAttributes("value", longstring);
```

Comment: Indeed the alternative to `sendKeys` would be to set the value of the `input` DOM element directly. However, you show only fragment of how you try to do it and you don't explain how the program "crashes" exactly. ("Crashes" is not precise at all.)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the Error message in the edit.

Comment: Your code is still showing only *fragments* of how you do it. You don't show how `input` gets a value. You do show how `inputField` gets a value but not `input`, which is a different variable.

Comment: That was unfortunately a typo. It should be `inputField` throughout. With `.value = longstring` the program executes fine, but doesn't actually set the value.

Comment: Similar for Python: [Set attribute of an element using webdriver](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/3387/2840) at SQA

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to set the element's value using the `executeScript` method of `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");
```

Comment: I get the same error as when I try to do `.value = longstring`  
Error: `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`

Comment: Could you please add sample of your html? Because for google this code work excellent. Possibly problem with your element on page (it's hidden i think)

Comment: I'm actually using this example to test it with google. Could you put your code that worked for you here, please?

Comment: here you are. `driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').setAttribute('value','Selenium Web Driver')");`

Comment: Indeed it works, I tried `getElementById` and used `q` which was the name of the inputfield instead of the real id. Thanks.

Comment: In Python Selenium it's execute_script

Comment: this is so beautiful, works on stubborn modern JS forms, and makes me love you like tapirs love twigs
python 
`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('an_id').setAttribute('value', 'my_username_or_w/e')")`

Comment: Seems to work but doesn't for file input fields. Even though calling getAttribute("value") on the element returns the string I used in setAttribute("xxx"), the file input field still thinks that no file has been selected. Either that or the change event hasn't been fired...

Comment: Can I see the solution in Ruby please?

Comment: It is worth to remaind that JS code could be checked in browser console before executing from webdriver.

Comment: For me when used new lines `(\n)` this worked 

**webdriver.executeScript(`document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS').innerHTML=\`${text}\``;**

Comment: OP explicitly said for NodeJS

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, using selenium webdriver and java/kotlin. No errors - it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 15):

Extending from the correct answer of Andrey-Egorov using `.executeScript()` to conclude my own question example:

```
inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('gbqfq'));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + longstring +"')", inputField);
```

Comment: Yeah, this also will work. But also can be modified, to be more simplier: `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", inputField, longstring);`

Comment: `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value = '" + longstring + "'", inputField)` is another possible improvement that also works with textAreas (I've only tested in Chrome, though)

Comment: A slight modification to the above 2 ideas because at least in my context I was trying to set a textarea and it complained about the syntax. This is in protractor: browser.executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1].toString()", inputField, longstring); I also found that to make the field update, it helped to then inputField.sendKeys(" "), where in my context the extra space was harmless.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to Andrey Egorov, in my case with python `setAttribute` not working, but I found I can set the property directly,

Try this code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('q').value='value here'")
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way of sending a large number of repeating characters to a text field (for instance to test the maximum number of characters the field will allow) is to type a few characters and then repeatedly copy and paste them:

```
inputField.sendKeys('0123456789');
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    inputField.sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'a'));
    inputField.sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'c'));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        inputField.sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'v'));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately pressing CTRL doesn't seem to work for IE unless `REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS` is enabled (which can cause other issues), but it works fine for Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andrey-Egorov and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285793/4117068), I've managed to do it in C#

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string value = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");
```

Comment: What's new in your answer in comparison with previous answers?

Comment: @Stepan - not much, but none of the answers were in C# which is what I was looking for but couldn't find it anywhere. So here it is. It could help someone like me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, this is the code which works for me :)

```
WebDriver driver;
WebElement element;
String value;

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ value +"';", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some variable, you may use this way:

```
String value= "your value";
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('q').value=' "+value+" ' ");
```

Comment: When writing a code snippet, use the code icon to write them.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('attributeValue').value='new value'");
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, here's how I've managed to do this in Java

```
public static void sendKeysJavascript(By element, String keysToSend) {
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(element);
    JavascriptExecutor ex = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    ex.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ keysToSend +"';", el);
}
```