# How can I input email address using Appium

Tags: android, appium

When I try to input email address like "test@gmail.com" during doing android automation using Appium, it always end up as "test2gmail.com". My code is as following:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new         URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
WebElement email = driver.findElementby(...);
email.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
```

I also tried:

```
WebElement email = driver.findElementby(...);
email.sendKeys("test");
email.click();
driver.sendKeyEvent(77);//Key code constant: '@' key.
email.sendKeys("gmail.com");
```

It doesn't work either. Can somebody please help me on this.

Comment: Could you please share your OS and browser?

Comment: Hi @Eugene, I am using: Samsung Galaxy Tab S (real device not emulator) with Android version 5.0.2. 
Appium version 1.4.0. 
And the automation is based on Android app not browser.
Thank.

Comment: Is the solution works on the simulator or/and other device? I am asking if the problem occurs only on the described Galaxy?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening for me on the Galaxy Note 2

As @LagiNatoRRR said, you can try unicode, but in python you might need to make that string

```
u"test\u0040gmail.com"
```

Try passing in these capabilities, it worked for me:

```
"unicodeKeyboard": True
"resetKeyboard": True
```

Comment: Thanks jwallis and @LagiNatoRRR, that seems to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your email field has ID `email`:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor)
  js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('value', 'test@gmail.com')");
```

Source: [Set value of input instead of sendKeys() - selenium webdriver nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583641/set-value-of-input-instead-of-sendkeys-selenium-webdriver-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

As another variant using unicode representation of @:

```
email.sendKeys("test\u0040gmail.com");
```