# Method SendKeys is very slow on IE11

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

I'm using a SendKeys method to write text in a field.
But on IE11, the writting is too slow, and my script shutdown cause a timeout.

I don't know how resolve this problem.

Comment: You need to provide more than that or only psychics will be able to answer your problem.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584027/2365564) might help !

Comment: I resolved my problem with my psychics powers !

It was a compatibility problem with the IEDriverServer. I used x86 instead of x64.

Comment: Can you improve this question and provide a detailed answer as to how you solved the issue? As it stands now this question is poor quality and a candidate for deletion. The idea is to provide enough background in the question such that other users with the same problem can identify the issue and your answer should provide enough detail so that they can then solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had Similar issue with IE11 on Windows x64 bit. I was using 64bit version of IEDriverServer.exe (IE driver-2.39.0 with selenium-3.0.1).

After I changed to 32bit version of IEDriverServer.exe, it solved the issue