# Sendkeys only passes partial information to input box in Firefox browser using protractor

Tags: firefox, protractor, sendkeys

Here is my code:
basePage.webAppPage.inputFrom.sendKeys("WAT");

But it only enters "WA" to my input box.

Although the same script works fine for chrome.

Comment: You can try to use JS executeScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584027/6331748 .

Comment: Also you can try to send each symbol.

Comment: Any better solution for this yet?