# Change Element in Python using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, element

I have been researching for a way to change the element of a web page and have yet found (or understood) how to do it.
In the above element I want to be able to change numerical value of  to another number that is represented by a placeholder (i.e. nod for number of draws. Or do I have to do it manually every time I run the program?).

My OS is Ubunt 18.04 and using latest python, selenium and pycharm IDE.

These are just a couple of the websites I have visited and I have visited a lot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdgAIDR9snc

http://allselenium.info/javascript-using-python-selenium-webdriver/

[Set value of input instead of sendKeys() - selenium webdriver nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583641/set-value-of-input-instead-of-sendkeys-selenium-webdriver-nodejs)

WEBELEMENT:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlRange" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange">
    <option selected="selected" value="1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Single Draw</option>
    <option value="2"> &nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
    <option value="3"> &nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
    <option value="4"> &nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
    <option value="5"> &nbsp;&nbsp;5&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
    <option value="10">10&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
    <option value="20">20&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
</select>
```

And my basic code is:

```
from Selenium import WebDriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
page=browser.get("whatever address of whatever webpage interested in")

elem=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('<option selected="selected" value="20">','20&nbsp;Consecutive</option>')", elem)
```

My goal is to change the value number in the first part of the option tag from:

```
<option selected="selected" value="1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Single Draw</option>
```

to this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="44"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Single Draw</option>
```

In the execute_script I am always getting end of statement expected after the last ).
I am also getting errors of ',' or ')' expected in the areas of "selected" and "20"

Also the css and xpath selectors to these are:

```
for <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlRange" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange">
selector = #ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange
xpath    = //*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange"]

for <option>
selector = #ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange > option:nth-child(1)   (note that nth-child() can be 1 - 7)
xpath    = //*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlRange"]/option[1]     (note that option[] can also be 1 - 7)
```

I have the webpage saved to disc and I can go into the html and change that one number then save the file and when I click on it works. I just want to be able to automate it.

Any help is much appreciated

Idzireit

EDIT:

So far this is the closest I have come to actually inserting the value I want. The new code is as follows:

```
browser.execute_script("""arguments[0].setAttribute
('select', '<option selected="selected" value="nod"> &nbsp;&snbsp;draws </option>')""", get_draws)
```

Results in this:

```
<option value="20" select="<option selected=&quot;selected&quot; value=&quot;nod&quot;> &amp;nbsp;&amp;snbsp;draws </option>">20&nbsp;Consecutive</option>
```

The javascript I am trying to inject is getting injected in the middle of the element I am trying to modify (notice the option sequence repeats in the middle of the first bracket).

How can I correct this to make it look like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="a number I am trying to change"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Draw<\option>
```

EDIT SOLVED:

Figured out how to change the value of an element. I had to change the search method of that element to this:

```
get_draws = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('option')
```

Then my next line was pretty simple:

```
browser.execute_script("""arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '100')""", get_draws)
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/55915856/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You need to escape the " " characters around the 'selected' and '20'.

Comment: DebanjanB My apologies for rambling about ideas in other parts that I think have an affect on my code but simply put is how do it get the tag [option selected="selected" value="2"] to be [option selected="selected" value="34"]  MateMrse not sure I understand what you mean by escaping the " " characters.

Comment: @idzireit Update the question with the relevant HTML please

Comment: DebanjanB Hope this is edited correctly for you.

Comment: @idzireit I wish moving forward you add the `@` before the username else the messages are not delivered directly to the inbox. I will take a relook in a couple of hours, once I reach home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, parametrizing the int value, try the following:

```
var = 100
js = f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{var}')"
browser.execute_script(js, get_draws)
```

Just pass the value you want to the `var` variable.

Comment: actually a moderator deleted the answer.  Was up late last night so when I read your message I was wondering if I did and tried to undelete it but said moderator deleted it.  Wonder why ?  Oh yeah btw that worked great thanks.