# How to set "value" to input using Selenium when "element not interactable"

Tags: javascript, selenium

my code look like this:

```js
Integer unitOrder = Integer.valueOf(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(2));
purchaseOrderData.setOrderUnit(unitOrder);
typeOn(ORDER_FIELD_INGREDIENT, String.valueOf(unitOrder));
```

I have tried this code:

```js
getDriver().findElement(ORDER_FIELD_INGREDIENT).sendKeys("value", "16");
```

but still got this error: "element not interactable"

Comment: Can you share the link?
Will adding some wait help there?

Comment: Using javaScript executor will help you (every time you have to cheat, so to speak)
check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583641/set-value-of-input-instead-of-sendkeys-selenium-webdriver-nodejs