# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am not able to click on the button i am getting error that element is not visible and i have tried by using xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'][@name='btn_discuss']")).click();
```

but is not working

```
<button type="submit" name="btn_discuss"> View Details</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your element is not visible. Thats the reason Selenium couldn't able to `click` on it.

Are you sure the element is visible? According to Selenium an element is visible if:

- visibility != hidden
- display != none (is also checked against every parent element)
- opacity != 0 (this is not checked for clicking an element)
- height and width are both > 0
- for an input, the attribute type != hidden

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/selenium-2-0-element-is-not-currently-visible) for more info.