# Dropdown cannot be selected in Selenium - Element not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I'm attempting to select a dropdown box via Selenium and am being told the following

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

After searching around a bit I've tried the following but am still being given the same error:

```
        WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By
                .id("diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime"));

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].checked = true;", inputElement);

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].checked = true;", inputElement);

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("$(\"#diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime\").show()");

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].checked = true;", inputElement);

        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        new Select(inputElement).selectByVisibleText("Dinner");
```

However,this results in the same error.  When I open the page in the browser I can see the dropdown, I can also click on the dropdown.  However, like I said - using this bit of code doesn't achieve what I need.

The input Element returns as the value is correct.  Made sure to check it was correct by throwing in some errors and it failed as expected.

EDIT 2:

Here's the HTML

```html
 <span class="selectBox medium standardFormElement status-closed" id="searchTime-wrapper" data-plugins="[[&quot;pepSelectBox&quot;,{&quot;maxSelectionsLength&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;maxDisplayOptions&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;displayScrollBar&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;displaySpecialDropDown&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;displaySpecialDropDownHeight&quot;:&quot;21&quot;,&quot;checkIconActive&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;highlightSelected&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]]"
data-prependliststyleenhancements="[]" data-appendliststyleenhancements="[]" data-richoptioncontents="[]" data-extraoptionclass="[]" data-richoptgroup="[]" data-a11ytext=" - Opens menu">
      <span class="selectBox-nojs" style="display: none;">
         <select name="searchTime" id="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime" class="searchTime inputElement" min="06:30:00" max="22:30:00" allday="00:00:00 23:30:00" data-plugins="[[&quot;pepMealTimeOptionModifier&quot;]]">
            <option value="80000712" label="Breakfast" selected="selected">Breakfast</option>
            <option value="80000717" label="Lunch">Lunch</option>
            <option value="80000714" label="Dinner">Dinner</option>
         </select>
      </span>
<span class="richSelectArrowIcon uiGlobalSprite"></span>
<div class="select-toggle hoverable" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-dropdown-list" aria-describedby="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-label" aria-labelledby="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-label" role="button" tabindex="0"><span class="select-value" data-activeoptionclass=""><span class="rawOption"><span class="accessibleText hidden">Time&nbsp;required  - Opens menu - </span>Dinner</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="listWrapper">
  <span class="scrollbarTrack"></span>
  <div class="innerListWrapper">
    <ol class="dropdown-list" id="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-dropdown-list" aria-hidden="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Time&amp;nbsp;required  - Opens menu">
      <li role="option" data-value="80000712" data-display="breakfast" data-extraoptionclass="" class="selectOption" id="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-0" aria-setsize="36" aria-posinset="1"><span class="rawOption"><span class="accessibleText hidden">Time&nbsp;required  - Opens menu - </span>Breakfast</span>
      </li>
      <li role="option" data-value="80000717" data-display="lunch" data-extraoptionclass="" class="selectOption" id="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-1" aria-setsize="36" aria-posinset="2"><span class="rawOption"><span class="accessibleText hidden">Time&nbsp;required  - Opens menu - </span>Lunch</span>
      </li>
      <li role="option" data-value="80000714" data-display="dinner" data-extraoptionclass="" class="selectOption" id="diningAvailabilityForm-searchTime-2" aria-setsize="36" aria-posinset="3">
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<span class="shadow-mask"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you please share the html and the code for finding `inputElement`?

Comment: Have you tried `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].checked = true;", inputElement);`? (from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/selenium-2-0-element-is-not-currently-visible)

Comment: @Sid yes I've tried that - no dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"selectBox-nojs\")[1].style.display = ''");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"selectBox-nojs\")[2].style.display = ''");
```

Comment: Hey, can you add some details explaining what's different between your answer and the code the questioner pasted? That'll help improve the quality of your response

Answer (score 1):

You are probarly trying to use the element before it is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by)));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)));
```

Effective wait methods for your situation

If it didnt work, you could also try

```
waitUntil(Waits.elementDisplayed(WebElement));
```

Comment: Doing this resulted in the following

Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for condition (visibility of element located by By.className: searchTime) to be refreshed