# Selenide test fails to interact with Material`s checkbox

Tags: material-ui, selenide

Dear stackoverflowers.

We are using Selenide framework in our project to write automation tests for UI.
We switched to Material-UI recently and faced with technical problems when it comes to simple [checkbox](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox).
I am trying to select checkbox.

```
SelenideElement rememberMeCheckBox = $(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"checkbox\"]"));

rememberMeCheckBox.setSelected(isSelected);
```

But while doing that I get an exception:

```
Element should be visible {input[type="checkbox"]}
Element: '<input type="checkbox" value="on" displayed:false></input>'
```

And indeed when I check the real DOM it contains `opacity: 0`:

[image]

When I set the opacity by force my automation tests works well. **How to deal with that ?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a Selenide problem, but a common Selenium problem. 
Selenium defines elements with "opacity: 0" as invisible. 
See [How to force Selenium WebDriver to click on element which is not currently visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib)

One simple way to enable this checkbox is to click its parent element:

```
$("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").parent().click();
```

At least it works for me.

Comment: It worked for me too. But I am wondering how to pick specific checkbox among a few ones. What attribute shall we use apart from type?

Comment: Nobody can answer but you. It depends on your application. You need to find some locator or at least xpath.