# Select Javascript created element in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have the following element in a web page.

```
<button type="submit" class="zsg-button_primary contact-submit-button track-ga-event" data-ga-category="contact" data-ga-action="email" data-ga-label="rentalbuilding" data-ga-event-content="false" data-ga-event-details="" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1482045459111_1278">
   <span class="zsg-loading-spinner hide"></span>
   <span class="button-text" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1482045459111_1277">Contact Property Manager</span>
</button>
```

I can find this element with Beautifulsoup using:

```
e = soup.find('button', attrs={'class' : 'zsg-button_primary'})
```

But when I try with Selenium using:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("zsg-button_primary").click()
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I think this is because the element is being created in Javascript and is doing something funny but I can see it on the screen and I just don't know how to get it so I can click it.  Any help most welcome.

**EDIT**

I've been pointed toward [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib) which is for Selenium Javascript.  I need to do this with Python is anyone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Selenium WebDriver to click on element which is not currently visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait until your element become visible with following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="zsg-button_primary contact-submit-button track-ga-event"]')))
```

Comment: Surely it is already visible because it is being picked up by BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @HenryM, actually, no. `bsp` handles scraped `HTML` source, while `selenium`- browser window. Presence in page source doesn't mean that element is visible

Comment: so how do I make it visible because without a prompt it just sites there

Comment: Your locator is too broad. `find_element_by_class_name("zsg-button_primary")` will find first element with specified class name. while there could be more than one element with this attribute. Does `len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("zsg-button_primary"))` returns `1`?

Comment: No, you're right.  I need to get the first button with that class