# Element not clickable error using Actions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the search area in this page
http://test1.absofttrainings.com

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class FindProduct  {

    @Test
    public void findProduct(){

        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://test1.absofttrainings.com/");

        WebElement search_link=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='et_search_icon']"));

        Actions action= new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(search_link).build().perform();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='et_search_icon']")).click();


    }

}
```

I am getting Element Not visible exception. I have tried using implicitlyWait but that did not work either. Your suggestion/advise is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("et_top_search")).click();
```

or use JS

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('et_search_icon').click();");
```

Have a look at this link [How to force Selenium WebDriver to click on element which is not currently visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib)

There are certain rules based on which "Selenium" determines an element is visible or not (make sure you look at computed style):

1. visibility != hidden
2. display != none (is also checked against every parent element)
3. opacity != 0 (this is not checked for clicking an element)
4. height and width are both > 0
5. for an input, the attribute type != hidden

May be the span element is NOT matching any of the above criteria.

**The span tag has a height and width as 0** and hence selenium is unable to find the element. See the attachment[image]