# Selenium Webdriver findelements able to gettext of elements but not able to click

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, gettext, element

I am trying to get all the elements from a dropdown menu using the following code:

```
List<WebElement> actmenu = driver.findElements(By.className("mbrMenuItems")); 
    for (int i = 0; i < actmenu.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(actmenu.get(i).getText());
    }
    actmenu.get(0).click();
    actmenu.get(1).click();
```

So, I am able to print the link text using the for loop but I am not able to click on the elements, throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 30.31 seconds
```

any help in solving this error?

Comment: Did you check this element in the UI? is it visible or hidden?

Comment: You might have a look a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib) for the same problem with visible element

Comment: It is a visible element in UI, I am able to get the text of all the links in the drop down menu using the for loop. I am not able to click it

Comment: Did you try to click by using java script like the post I proposed?

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on? What's the complete output of the program? What happens when the links are clicked? Does it leave the page or ?

Comment: The exception is thrown on the line actmenu.get(0).click(); 
The output is just to go to that link. 
When the link is clicked it will open the link page.
I just want to open the link page by clicking on the WebElement in the List

Comment: Can you give us HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

The method `.getText()` returns value from HTML source. Maybe the element you are trying to click is not yet rendered? Try to wait for an element

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);`

The above code will wait 10 seconds until the element is visible.