# Laravel Dusk how to check if element is visible/clickable?

Tags: laravel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I have a scenario where I'd like not check **IF an element exists and is visible/clickable**. If not, script processing continues.

While *Laravel Dusk* provides `$browser->assertVisible($selector)` method, this ends up in an exception if the element is not visible. Or `$browser->waitFor('.selector');` but this also ends the script processing if element doesn't appear.

Here is the criteria Selenium uses to check for an element being visible is found here: [How to force Selenium WebDriver to click on element which is not currently visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib)

Apparently Dusk doesn't provide this kind of method. What would be the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better late than never I suppose.

isDisplayed() works pretty well (though not if it's covered up by other elements)...

```
if($browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#my-selector'))->isDisplayed()) {
    // do something
}
```

if I have overlays covering my elements, I use ->waitUntilMissing(), or in extreme cases I call on $browser->driver->executeScript() and run some jQuery to temporarily manipulate an element that is "in the way".

Answer (score 3):

You can try to find the element and try to retrieve properties of it. If the properties are empty, the element is not visible. E.g.

```
$hiddenBtn = $browser->element('@show-more');
if($hiddenBtn && $hiddenBtn->getText()){
    $browser->click('@show-more');    
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without a good idea of what you're trying to accomplish you can always wait until the element is visible:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#waiting-for-elements

Comment: I need is to check if an element is there, so it is an IF scenario... Waiting for an element is a blocking scenario where the element absolutely needs to be present or the processing is halted after the wait time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$browser->whenAvailable('.modal', function (Browser $modal) {
    $modal->assertSee('Hello World')
          ->press('OK');
});
```