# Katalon Selenium Element is visible but displayed is false

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm trying to click a button in vue js with [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) with selenium/katalon. It is fully visible in the UI but still can be clicked on. I can find the element with no issues, but clicking on it returns a element not visible error. I tried various [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib) including:

- clicking with javascript (The js performs the click script but does NOT click the button)
- using the Action class to move to the element and then click on it (it does NOT move to the element)
- focusing and scrolling to the element
- waits
- switch to active element, default content, and maximize window
- no parent elements with display none

When debugging I noticed the following:

```
// Able to find element with no issues
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
String xPathForButton = "//div[@id='validationStepper']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]";
def element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
// Element not visible exception
element.click();

KeywordUtil.logInfo('X: ' + element.getLocation().x); // Prints 0
KeywordUtil.logInfo('Y: ' + element.getLocation().y); // Prints 0
KeywordUtil.logInfo('Element is enabled: ' + element.isEnabled()); // Prints true
KeywordUtil.logInfo('Element is displayed: ' + element.isDisplayed()); // Prints false
```

I need to use the xpath to find this element. Can someone help me on how I can properly detect and click on this element?

Comment: Which element are you _trying to click_? Your code trials?

Comment: The button. I have no issues finding it. But when I click it throws a not visible exception, even though its visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that a parent element was `display: none` during runtime. While I had no parent elements initially that were displayed none, the CSS changed dynamically, causing this to happen. I made corrections and afterwards the element was visible.