# Issue with Extracting All Nodes Using Java Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chromium, devtools

I'm implementing a web scraper using Java Selenium and have encountered an issue. While I need to scrape a total of 524 data points, only 512 are being extracted.

In my investigation, noticed a "show all nodes (12 more)" entry in the node tree of Chrome DevTools, leading me to believe that this is the reason for failing to fetch the remaining 12 data points.

As evidence, out of the 505 data points extracted, when attempting to scrape data from a different range, I managed to scrape 500, and the message "show all nodes (5 more)" appeared. I suspect this is related to Chrome hiding nodes for performance reasons. However, I would like to disable this feature and collect all the data. I've been searching for a solution, but haven't been able to find one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Chrome Devtools in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNRW8.png)

"I have added the code."

```
public class Page {
       
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"myTable\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")
private List<WebElement> dataTable;
       
public Page(WebDriver webDriver){
     ElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(webDriver, 10);
     PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
  }
       
  public int getDataTableSize(){
     return dataTable.size();
  }

  public Popup openDataPopupByIndex(int index){
        if(dataTable.size() <= index){
            return null;
        }
        orderCodesByDataTable.get(index).click();
        return new Popup(...);
    } 
}
```

Here is a simple code snippet I have written. It doesn't contain much information, but it doesn't deviate much from the provided code. I have structured the code using the Page Object Model (POM). I have tried testing with Thread.sleep(), set waiting time with WebDriverWait, and used @FindBy with CSS selectors, but the issue persists and remains unresolved.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visib) can help.

Comment: Don't ask the dev tools, ask selenium itself. Chrome's dev tools is telling you that there's so much data it thinks it's wise to hide part of it, which has nothing to do with what Selenium (or Chrome itself for that matter) finds when it queries a document. So: [show your code](/help/how-to-ask), in [mcve] form. Otherwise it's almost certainly a matter of "you probably wrote the wrong code for what you're trying to do".