# How to scroll page with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using FirefoxDriver webdriver. The page that loads in Firefox window is a large page and I want to scroll that page using selenium.

I want to know how this can be done.

Comment: You should **focus** to the desired item and the selenium 2 will take care of finding it. Look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

Comment: I am assuming you are wanting to use the Selenium API, Here's a link to scrolling a page using the Selenium API. [Scroll Page](http://testerinyou.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-scroll-page.html)

Comment: driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {2**127});")

Answer (score 12):

If you want to scroll on the firefox window using selenium webdriver, one of the way is to use javaScript in the java code, The javeScript code to scroll down is as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," + "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should do something like

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to scroll single page down

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE).perform();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct key to send? It seems it would the a `backspace` key press, which would not scroll the page.

Comment: Page Down key perhaps?

Comment: Oh dear #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

```
page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to( find("element").native,100,100)
```