# How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am currently using selenium webdriver to parse through facebook user friends page and extract all ids from the AJAX script. But I need to scroll down to get all the friends. How can I scroll down in Selenium. I am using python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll page with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433223/how-to-scroll-page-with-selenium)

Comment: driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {2**127});")

Comment: If in your case that there is a list of items, so you can follow this method stackoverflow.com/a/68970174/12272687

Answer (score 480):

**You can use**

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

where Y is the height (on a fullhd monitor it's 1080). (Thanks to @lukeis)

**You can also use**

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

to scroll to **the bottom of the page.**

If you want **to scroll to a page with infinite loading**, like social network ones, facebook etc. (thanks to @Cuong Tran)

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

another method (thanks to Juanse) is, select an object and

```
label.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: Excellent, can you explain a little bit on `scrollHeight`, what does it mean and how does it work in general?

Comment: How would you then use the variable "last_height"?

I have something similar in my code and the browser is scrolling down. However, when I look at the data I'm scraping it only scrapes the data from the first page k times with "k" being the number of times the browser scrolls down.

Comment: @JasonGoal hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675563/6907424

Comment: `driver.execute_script` can be combined with smooth scrolling (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to imitate more human-like behavior!

Comment: Goodness this is pure gold!

Answer (score 113):

If you want to **scroll down to bottom of infinite page** (like [linkedin.com](https://www.linkedin.com)), you can use this code:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28928684/1316860

Comment: This is great.  For anyone who is trying to use this on instagram, you may need to first tab to the "Load more" button using ActionChains, then apply Cuong Tran's solution... at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I would like to do is scroll for instance in instagram to the bottom of the page, then grab the entire html of the page. Is there a function in selenium where I could give last_height as input and get the entire page html, after I have scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: The `SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME` varies, it takes around 2 seconds for me.

Answer (score 75):

You can use [`send_keys`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) to simulate an [`END` (or `PAGE_DOWN`) key press](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys) (which normally scroll the page):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
html = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: Tried PAGE_DOWN on a loop and did not behave as expected, END worked as expected for w/e reason

Comment: Guys, one thing I was trying to do.... send the keys to press like a value from a function....
ex: my_func(value):....html.send_keys(Keys.<value>).
any help is welcome... thanks

Comment: `find_element_by_tag_name` is not longer supported in Selenium. Also keys will not work on pages like Facebook.

Answer (score 29):

same method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195714/725944):

in python you can just use

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

(Y is the vertical position you want to scroll to)

Answer (score 26):

```
element=find_element_by_xpath("xpath of the li you are trying to access")

element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

this helped when I was trying to access a 'li' that was not visible.

Comment: 'find_element_by_xpath' is a driver function or what, the '.location_once_scrolled_into_view' returns error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="timeline-medley"]/div/div[2]/div[1]"}

Comment: Just one more thing. The reason why `location_once_scrolled_into_view` should be called without `()`  is that `location_once_scrolled_into_view` is a Python `property`. see the source code here: [selenium/webelement.py at d3b6ad006bd7dbee59f8539d81cee4f06bd81d64 · SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d3b6ad006bd7dbee59f8539d81cee4f06bd81d64/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py)

Answer (score 22):

For my purpose, I wanted to scroll down more, keeping the windows position in mind. My solution was similar and used `window.scrollY`

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
```

which will go to the current y scroll position + 200

Answer (score 13):

This is how you scroll down the webpage:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way i found to solve that problem was to select a label and then send:

```
label.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Can you please show us example code to select a label?

Answer (score 9):

None of these answers worked for me, at least not for scrolling down a facebook search result page, but I found after a lot of testing this solution:

```
while driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    Divs=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').text
    if 'End of Results' in Divs:
        print 'end'
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: It works, but very slow (for me at least). I found that if you set `SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/7326714 to `2`, it works just fine and you scroll down a 100x faster.

Answer (score 9):

When working with youtube the floating elements give the value "0" as the scroll height
so rather than using **"return document.body.scrollHeight"** try using this one **"return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"**
adjust the scroll pause time as per your internet speed 
else it will run for only one time and then breaks after that.

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
"""last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

this dowsnt work due to floating web elements on youtube
"""

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
       print("break")
       break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 9):

scroll loading pages. Example: medium, quora,etc

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-1000);")
        # Wait to load the page.
        driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        # sleep for 30s
        driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: should driver.quit() be outside the while block or not? and also the last implicit wait is not required.. someone pls confirm. @ashishmishra

Comment: No, if driver.quit() was inside the while loop, the driver would be closed each iteration of the loop. Once there is no more length to the page, then it will quit. The last wait could be there to give the page time to load?

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example selenium code snippet that you could use for this type of purpose. It goes to the url for youtube search results on 'Enumerate python tutorial' and scrolls down until it finds the video with the title: 'Enumerate python tutorial(2020).'

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=enumerate+python')
target = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Enumerate python tutorial(2020).')
target.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a way of scrolling through a dynamic webpage, and automatically stopping once the end of the page is reached, and found this thread.

The post by [@Cuong Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299513/4852724), with one main modification, was the answer that I was looking for. I thought that others might find the modification helpful (it has a pronounced effect on how the code works), hence this post.

The modification is to move the statement that captures the last page height **inside** the loop (so that each check is comparing to the previous page height).

So, the code below:

> Continuously scrolls down a dynamic webpage (`.scrollTo()`), only stopping when, for one iteration, the page height stays the same.

*(There is another modification, where the break statement is inside another condition (in case the page 'sticks') which can be removed).*

```
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


    while True:

        # Get scroll height
        ### This is the difference. Moving this *inside* the loop
        ### means that it checks if scrollTo is still scrolling 
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:

            # try again (can be removed)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

            # check if the page height has remained the same
            if new_height == last_height:
                # if so, you are done
                break
            # if not, move on to the next loop
            else:
                last_height = new_height
                continue
```

Answer (score 7):

This code scrolls to the bottom but doesn't require that you wait each time. It'll continually scroll, and then stop at the bottom (or timeout)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://example.com')

pre_scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
run_time, max_run_time = 0, 1
while True:
    iteration_start = time.time()
    # Scroll webpage, the 100 allows for a more 'aggressive' scroll
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 100*document.body.scrollHeight);')

    post_scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')

    scrolled = post_scroll_height != pre_scroll_height
    timed_out = run_time >= max_run_time

    if scrolled:
        run_time = 0
        pre_scroll_height = post_scroll_height
    elif not scrolled and not timed_out:
        run_time += time.time() - iteration_start
    elif not scrolled and timed_out:
        break

# closing the driver is optional 
driver.close()
```

This is much faster than waiting 0.5-3 seconds each time for a response, when that response could take 0.1 seconds

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **send_keys** to simulate a **PAGE_DOWN** key press (which normally scroll the page):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: That's exactly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python/63795903#51345544), simply more vague

Comment: this the only code that works with me on the Specific page I work on
but I must click on the slider with the mouse to work I don't know why I should do that and i try find another solution for my problem

Comment: the page i works on: https://contacts.google.com/u/0/directory

Answer (score 3):

if you want to scroll **within a particular view/frame** (WebElement), what you only need to do is to replace "body" with a particular element that you intend to scroll within. i get that element via "getElementById" in the example below:

```
self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById("page-manager").scrollHeight);')
```

this is the case on **YouTube**, for example...

Answer (score 3):

The `ScrollTo()` function doesn't work anymore. This is what I used and it worked fine.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollIntoView();")
```

Comment: Only this method worked in my case, not other worked. Thanks.

Comment: worked for me too. If you're calling scrollIntoView multiple times, be sure to set a setTimeout() function in order to allow the page to load the new content, or it won't find the new element. On a side note, to find an elem by href you can do: driver.execute_script(document.querySelector(\"a[href=\'your_href_link\']\").scrollIntoView();")

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.scroll),
the class `ActionChains` does the job:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.scroll(x: int, y: int, delta_x: int, delta_y: int, duration: int = 0, origin: str = 'viewport').perform()
```

Answer (score 2):

insert this line `driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,925)", "")`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The loop using the "send keys" method of scrolling the page:

```
pre_scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(5)
    post_scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')

    print(pre_scroll_height, post_scroll_height)
    if pre_scroll_height == post_scroll_height:
        break
    pre_scroll_height=post_scroll_height
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I wrote to slowly scroll down to a targets element

You can pass either Y-th position of element of the CSS Selector to it

It scrolls exactly like we do via mouse-wheel

Once this method called, you call it again with same driver object but with new target element, it will then scroll up/down wherever that element exists

```
def slow_scroll_to_element(self, driver, element_selector=None, target_yth_location=None):
    current_scroll_position = int(driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY"))
    
    if element_selector:
        target_yth_location = int(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('{}').getBoundingClientRect()['top'] + window.scrollY".format(element_selector)))
    
    scrollSpeed = 100 if target_yth_location-current_scroll_position > 0 else -100

    def chunks(a, n):
        k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
        return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))
    
    for l in list(chunks(list(range(current_scroll_position, target_yth_location, scrollSpeed)) + list([target_yth_location+(-scrollSpeed if scrollSpeed > 0 else scrollSpeed)]), 3)):
        for pos in l:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(pos)+");")
            time.sleep(0.1)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scroll to an element**: Find the element and scroll using this code.

```
scroll_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your element xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('your ID Element').scrollIntoView();")
```

it's working for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small variation of the solutions provided so far: sometimes in scraping you have to meet the following requirements:

- Keep scrolling step by step. Otherwise if you always jump to the bottom some elements are loaded only as containers/divs but their content is not loaded because they were never visible (because you jumped straight to the bottom);
- Allow enough time for content to be loaded;
- It's **not** an infinite scroll page, there is an end and you have to identify when the end is reached;

Here is a simple implementation:

```
from time import sleep
def keep_scrolling_to_the_bottom():
    while True:
        previous_scrollY = my_web_driver.execute_script( 'return window.scrollY' )
        my_web_driver.execute_script( 'window.scrollBy( 0, 230 )' )
        sleep( 0.4 )
        if previous_scrollY == my_web_driver.execute_script( 'return window.scrollY' ):
            print( 'job done, reached the bottom!' )
            break
```

Tested and working on Windows 7 x64, Python 3.8.0, selenium 4.1.3, Google Chrome 107.0.5304.107, website for property rent.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using an extension of Selenium so you don't have to code everything yourself? I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package in full disclosure. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

[Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) has several options for scrolling. Whether it's scrolling to specific elements, a few pixels down or up, a whole page down or up, end or top of page, just a few lines of code is needed. Examples:

```py
from browserist import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.open.url("https://stackoverflow.com")
browser.scroll.into_view("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[6]")
browser.scroll.page.to_end()
browser.scroll.page.to_top()
browser.scroll.page.down()
browser.scroll.down_by(100)
browser.scroll.up_by(50)
```

Here's what I get (slowed down as [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) finishes the job quickly). I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Example of scrolling with Browserist]

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll to a specific element, position or end of the page :**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Find the target element you want to scroll to
element = driver.find_element_by_id("target-element-id")



# Scroll to the target element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

# Scroll to a specific position (x, y coordinates)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")

# Scroll to the end of the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are severals ways to this,  but all of them has a limitation if you are using them for infinite loading site.

The limitation is the **waiting time until new scroll happened** and this's very bad since we cannot be sure about others internet speed. Any way if I found any solution for this I'll update this post.

1st solution

```py
loading_waiting_time = 1

# Get actual page height
previous_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

# Run infinte loop and stop it if new_page_height is equal to previous_page_height
while True:
    # Scroll to the end of page
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')

    # Waiting until new images loaded
    time.sleep(loading_waiting_time)

    # Get new page height
    new_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_page_height == previous_page_height:
        break
    previous_page_height = new_page_height
```

2nd Solution
This solution is good for non fixed footer.

```py
loading_waiting_time = 1

# Get actual page height
previous_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

# Run infinte loop and stop it if new_page_height is equal to previous_page_height
while True:
    # Scroll to `footer` using JS
    footer_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'footer')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', footer_element)
    
    # Waiting until new images loaded
    time.sleep(loading_waiting_time)

    # Get new page height
    new_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_page_height == previous_page_height:
        break
    previous_page_height = new_page_height
```

3rd Solution
This solution is good for non fixed footer.

```py
loading_waiting_time = 1

# Get actual page height
previous_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

# Run infinte loop and stop it if new_page_height is equal to previous_page_height
while True:
    # Scroll to until `footer` is visible
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'footer')))

    # Waiting until new images loaded
    time.sleep(loading_waiting_time)

    # Get new page height
    new_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_page_height == previous_page_height:
        break
    previous_page_height = new_page_height
```