# Obtaining dynamic generated content with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I would like to obtain the content from this webpage: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_paid

The lower apps will only be displayed when I scroll down. I have tried several solutions such as:
[How to scroll down with Phantomjs to load dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561582/how-to-scroll-down-with-phantomjs-to-load-dynamic-content)

[Scroll down to bottom of infinite page with PhantomJS in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928068/scroll-down-to-bottom-of-infinite-page-with-phantomjs-in-python)

A working solution for the present content (directly available without scrolling) is:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_paid', function () {
    page.evaluate(function(){

    });

    page.render('export.png');
    fs.write('test.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Including `page.scrollPosition` does not help either.  How can I obtain the dynamically generated content?