# Retrieving all information from page BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am attempting to scrape the urls of the products on an OldNavy webpage. However, it is only giving parts of the products list instead of the whole thing (for example, giving only 8 urls when there are way more than 8). I was hoping someone could help and identify what the problem may be.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html5lib
import platform
import urllib
import urllib2
import json


link = http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=1035712&sop=true
base_url = "http://www.oldnavy.com"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(link)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
bigDiv = soup.findAll("div", class_="sp_sm spacing_small")
for div in bigDiv:
  links = div.findAll("a")
  for i in links:
    j = j + 1
    productUrl = base_url + i["href"]
    print productUrl
```

Comment: this code doesn't work - you have url without `""` and error with `j`. Check code before you put in question.

Answer (score 5):

This page uses `JavaScript` to load elements but it loads only when you scroll down page.

It is called `"lazy loading"`.

You have to scroll page too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

link = "http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=1035712&sop=true"
base_url = "http://www.oldnavy.com"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(link)

# ---

# scrolling

lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
#print(lastHeight)

pause = 0.5
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(pause)
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
        break
    lastHeight = newHeight
    #print(lastHeight)

# ---

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

#driver.find_element_by_class_name

divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="sp_sm spacing_small")
for div in divs:
    links = div.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
    print base_url + link["href"]
```

Idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28928684/1832058