# Scroll to bottom of <ul> that generates <li> tags when scrolling with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I have a `<ul>` with a special class that pops up in a modal. When you scroll down the modal, more `<li>` tags are generated in the list. I need to be able to scroll all the way down this `<ul>` until there are no more `<li>` tags left so that I can scrape the data. I've looked everywhere for something like this, but I can't seem to nail a proper algo.

Comment: I used to work in CasperJS, PhantomJS for scraping sites, so I referenced here in Python selenium. I believe this should work for you 
as answer is exactly for Python.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928068/scroll-down-to-bottom-of-infinite-page-with-phantomjs-in-python/28928684#28928684