# Selenium Python: How to Scroll Down in a Pop Up window

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am working on a Linkedin web scraping project. I am trying to get the list of companies that interest someone (notice I am not using the API). It is a dynamic website, so I would need to scroll down while scraping the names of the companies. I know how to do this in the MAIN window, but since Interest are a pop-up window [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python) solution to scroll does not work. My code so far was:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="entity-list row"]')
bar.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Since it didn't work, I also tried:

```
bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="entity-list row"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', bar)
```

The problem is that I am not acting on the pop up window but in the main one so it has not the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: Find the "scroll down" arrow css and click it until you find the element? That's how a human would do it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with JeffC. I added my code so far to make it more complete.

Answer (score 9):

You can try to find element inside popup (the one that can be focused), for example some anchor:

```
element_inside_popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="entity-list-wrapper ember-view"]//a')
```

and then use below code to scroll popup down:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element_inside_popup.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: Just a clarification: what does '//a' exactly do? I realized that without it, the code cannot focus the element. How would the driver know when the element is over so that it does not need to scroll down any more?

Comment: `//a` means to return you the any first link on popup. Do you want to scroll to the very bottom of popup or to specific element?

Comment: Thanks! I understand the '//a' magic now. I want to get the list of all companies and I realized this is only displayed fully if I get to the end of the element.

Comment: Oh. I see. You need to make XHR while complete list not received? Try `element_inside_popup.send_keys(Keys.END)` in a while loop. You should check the count of companies and if on some iteration there is no new companies- break the loop

Comment: I get this error  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <a class="class-small "> stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the document has been refreshed
.  any way to get arround it without time.sleep a bunch?

Comment: I need to check your code. Can you create new ticket and describe your issue there?

Comment: @Andersson Can you share the code with while loop and break statement to scroll the popup till end?

Answer (score 2):

first I tried with this script but it doesn't work:

```
scrollable_popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]')
for i in range(5):
    scrollable_popup.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(2)
```

and then I used this script and it works fine with me:

```
scrollable_popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[2]')
for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", scrollable_popup)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Both is not working

Comment: The second one is working fine for me .. verify the XPATH of the popup