# Scroll to the bottom of a dynamically loading dialog box in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dialog, webdriver, infinite-scroll

What I am trying to do is get all the followers of an instagram user. The problem is, the followers show up in a dialog box that is dynamically loading once you get to the bottom.
I found solutions to get to the bottom of an infinite window like in: [window scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)
or get to te bottom of a dialog box like in: [Pop up scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961116/selenium-python-how-to-scroll-down-in-a-pop-up-window)

But none of those work in my case.

This is my code:

```
import os
import random
import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/inbaral/followers/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.get(url)


username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="password"]')
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy       "]')

username.send_keys("name")
password.send_keys("pass")

#login
login_btn.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_changes('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/inbaral/followers/'))

#click on followers
followers_btn= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g47SY')
followers_btn[1].click()

# extract followers
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_changes('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/inbaral/followers/'))
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="FPmhX notranslate _0imsa "]')
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="lxml")
followers = soup.find_all("a",{'class':'FPmhX notranslate _0imsa '})

for follower in followers:
    print(follower.get_text())

driver.quit()
```

Note: Another problem is that sometimes the loading doesn't work when getting to the bottom, and the only way to fix it is by physically playing with the scrollbar

Comment: So how do you handle _...physically playing with the scrollbar..._ while _Test Execution_ takes place?

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div")
```

This never worked:

```
dialog.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

This worked for me(if I'm logged in):

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", dialog)
```

If i don't log in none of them works