# Scroll down to end page using Selenium Python chromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Please help, I want to scroll down to end of the bage but it stops.
the code that i try is here

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
button = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
old=""
new=" "

while len(new)>len(old):
    old = browser.page_source
    button.send_keys(Keys.END)
    browser.implicitly_wait(40)
    new = browser.page_source
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

your script for that

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

you can set no. of scrolls needed to get full length

```
scrolls = 4
while True:
    scrolls -= 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    if scrolls < 0:
        break
```

Comment: i hope it is not progressive web page, that content loads after page scrolling

Comment: there is a way for that

Comment: please can you  advise how many numbers to set for try, if number is bigger than needed,will it still work?

Comment: number is depend on site you are trying on.

Comment: What's the other way?