# Selenium not scrolling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a site that I want to scroll through using Selenium with Chrome and Python. Before, when I've wanted to scroll down, I've always given the following command:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

However, this website, for reasons I do not understand, is preventing me from scrolling. Does anyone have any advice?

Here is how to access the page I am having trouble with:

1. Go to https://shopwoodmans.com
2. Click "In Store"
3. Click on any store
4. Click on any of the "Shop Aisles" options

Comment: please provide your full working code with errors or exception stack trace

Comment: It's not giving me an exception. Selenium takes the **driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")** argument, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Code as follows:

import time
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from random import randint

chrome_path = r"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://shopwoodmans.com")

Comment: And then, manually navigate to the page in question, and try the **driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")** argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to scroll page down to trigger XHR, try below approach

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: @AlexHeebs , what if to call `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()` before scrolling?

Comment: Lucy van Pelt voice: "THAT'S IT!"

Thank you!

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but it doesn't work for me. Anyone else?