# How to scroll down on my page through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, webdriverwait

Trying to scroll down to the bottom of the page
https://silpo.ua/offers/?categoryId=13
but there is no result (no movements)

My code:

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

URL = "https://silpo.ua/offers/?categoryId=13"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)

page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
page.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

html = driver.page_source
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: Is this because selenium can't click on links that aren't in the viewport? We shouldn't need to do this anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several approaches to scroll down to the bottom of the page. As per the url `https://silpo.ua/offers/?categoryId=13` the **copyright** message is located at the bottom of the page. So you can use `scrollIntoView()` method to scroll the *copyright* message within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://silpo.ua/offers/?categoryId=13"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(URL)
copyright = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.copyrights")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", copyright)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! How can I consistently jump to all element with selector "product-list__item-image" ???  I can jump to the first, but can't jump to the next.

Answer (score 4):

You can move to the `copyright` class element at the bottom using `actions.move_to_element`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url ="https://silpo.ua/offers/?categoryId=13"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".copyrights")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

You can vary this, for example, say you wanted to go to last product:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-list__item-content")[-1]
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```