# How to scroll furthest to the right using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, webdriverwait

If I want to scroll to the end of a page I use the following:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

What's the equivalent for scrolling all the way to the right? My first guess was:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollWidth, 0);")
```

However, this didn't work and gave the following error:

> JavascriptException}Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties
> of null (reading 'scrollWidth')

I only want the so-called golf green (the green circle on the right)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directional scrolling an easier approach would be to identify the desired element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and invoke [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571886/7429447) as follows:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447)

---

### Update

To scrollIntoView the golf green (the green circle on the right) you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get(URL)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg g path[fill='#92f100']")))
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
driver.save_screenshot("green_circle_on_the_right.png")
```

Saved Screenshot:

[image: green_circle_on_the_right.png]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is that the element is huge and already in my viewport. So, running your code doesn't make the driver scroll to the right.

Comment: IMO, even scrolling and similtaneous screenshot even won't get you the whole picture. You have to adjust shooting strategy.

Comment: Yes, I know, so I only want the so-called golf green (the green circle on the right)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @HJA24 Approved your edit to hide the actual URL