# requests-html and infinite scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

I'm checking a python library: requests-html. Looks interesting, easy and clear scraping. However, I'm not sure how to render a page with infinite scrolling.

From their documentation I understand that I should render a page with special attribute (scrolldown). I'm trying but I do not know how exactly.  I know how to use selenium to handle infinite scroll, but I wonder whether it is possible with requests-html.

```
from requests_html import  HTML, HTMLSession

page1 = session.get(url1)
page1.html.render( scrolldown=5,sleep=3)
html = HTML(html=page1.text)
noticeName = html.find('h2.noticeName')
for element in noticeName:
    print(element.text)
```

It finds 10 elements from 13. 10 is visible without scrolling (and loading new content because of infinite scroll).

Comment: so what do you want actually ??

Comment: elements visible after scroll

Answer (score 0):

scrolldown=5 means scroll 5 pixel down, is your monitor that small?? or vm height that small?? now give it a bigger value like **height of the screen with sleep** or **2000 or 5000 without sleep**

And it will not give you uniquely next elements, it will give you exactly all elements from the starting.

I will add some sample code soon.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've solved this already, but I'll post this for any other curious souls.

In most cases, if you want to infinite scroll, *scrolldown* needs to be a large value because it is based on the number of times requests_html will send a "page down" request in Chromium.

According to the docs:

> **scrolldown** – Integer, if provided, of how many times to page down.

However, the requests_html uses the pyppeteer library which sends a page down as a key press. This means that if you are on a page that blocks the page down keys or simply doesn't infinite scroll using only the key presses, you will need a different solution.

[Alternative solution (in Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore)

[Documentation: requests_html (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210405204718/https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)