# How to scrapping web(bukalapak) with auto scrolling

Tags: python, data-science

I have data from https://mitra.bukalapak.com/lite/grosir/kopi

I am trying to extract information from this page. The page loads 7 items at a time, and I need to scroll to load all entries (for a total of 69). I am able to parse the HTML and get the information that I need for the first 10 entries, but I want to fully load all entries before parsing the HTML.

I am using python, selenium, and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499193/python-scraping-web-page-for-information-that-only-appears-after-scrolling) might point you towards the right direction.